# Identify intersection of multiple lists using multiple files from an input

Tags: python, loops, pandas, intersection, intersect

I am trying to write a code where it takes a Metadata.txt as an input, then it identifies the common genes across the different input files whose names are extracted from the Metadata.txt file.

Example of Metadata.txt

```
SIG1    SIG2
File1   File3
File2   File4
File3   File5
File4
```

The files in my directory are File1.xls, File2.xls, File3.xls...File6.xls. For simplicity, i have same inputs for File1 and File 3, as well as for File 2 and 4.

File1.xls or File3.xls

```
TargetID    FoldChange  p-value Adjusted-p
A   0.543528215 0.000518847 0.000518847
B   0.638469898 0.00204759  0.00204759
C   1.936595724 0.00250229  0.00250229
D   0.657322154 0.012840013 0.012840013
E   1.728842021 0.00251105  0.00251105
F   2.024842641 0.000719261 0.000719261
G   4.049059413 2.25E-05    2.25E-05
H   0.478660942 0.000352179 0.000352179
I   0.449304016 0.000489521 0.000489521
```

File2.xls or File4.xls

```
TargetID    FoldChange  p-value Adjusted-p
JJ  0.453537892 4.22E-06    4.22E-06
A   0.558325503 0.001697851 0.001697851
B   0.637336564 7.64E-05    7.64E-05
D   1.804853034 0.000492439 0.000492439
E   0.378445825 1.72E-05    1.72E-05
JJJJ    1.601997491 0.019618883 0.019618883
```

File5.xls

```
TargetID    FoldChange  p-value Adjusted-p
A   3.140223972 0.013347275 0.013347275
B   1.5205222   0.032318774 0.032318774
C   1.532760451 0.043763101 0.043763101
D   1.522865896 0.001791471 0.001791471
```

The goal is to output two files "SIG1.txt" and "SIG2.txt" which has the common genes between File1/File2 and File3/File4/File5, respectively. So the metadata is providing a platform to iterate over things. 
Here is what I had so far:

```
md_input = pd.read_table("Metadata.txt", sep="\t")  #opens the metadata file

for c in range(0, len(md_input.columns)):
        first_file=md_input.ix[0,c]+".xls"
        print first_file #this will print "File1.xls" for column1 and File3.xls for column#2
        first_sig=pd.read_table(first_file, sep="\t", usecols=["TargetID", 'FoldChange']) #opens the first file
        list1=list(first_file.iloc[:,0]) #takes column of first file and converts to list
        #Then, I aim to iterate over the remaining files in each column of the metadata and find the intersection/common with each other. I tried the following:
        for i in range(1, md_input.count()[c]):
            list2=[]
            df=pd.read_table("{}.xls".format(md_input.ix[i,c]), sep="\t", usecols=["TargetID", 'FoldChange'])
            list2=list(df.iloc[:,0]) #assign the LIST
            common=list(set(list_up_0).intersection(set(list2))) #find intersection

print common
```

When i print the 'common', i only get the common with the LAST file. Which is expected given how i wrote the loop/code. I am unable to find a way to iterate over all the files in the column, keep it open and then identify an intersection.

Please advise if i need to clarify the above further. I know it sounds complicated but it shouldn't be. t tried to simplify it and i hope that worked

Comment: Maybe you need some space in front of `print common`??? try to align with `common=list(set(list_up_0).intersection(set(list2))) #find intersection`...

Comment: that wouldn't solve it. it will just give you the common at each step then.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get it to work. I am not sure if this is the simplest way but it works. I think the confusing part in the script below is the utilization of the globals key to allow opening multiple files and assigning file names based on the # in the for loop. Anyway, the script works and it also takes into consideration the fold changes. I hope this will be useful to others.

```
md_input = pd.read_table('Metadata.txt', sep="\t")
list_cols=list(md_input.columns)
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=list_cols)
for c in range(0, len(md_input.columns)):
    sets_up=[]
    sets_down=[]
    for i in range(0, md_input.count()[c]):
        globals()["file_"+str(i)]=md_input.ix[i,c]+".xls"
        globals()["sig_"+str(i)]=pd.read_table(globals()["file_"+str(i)], sep="\t", usecols=["TargetID", 'FoldChange'])
        globals()["List_up"+str(i)]=[]
        globals()["List_down"+str(i)]=[]
        for z in range(0, len(globals()["sig_"+str(i)].index)):
            if globals()["sig_"+str(i)].ix[z,'FoldChange']>=1.5:
                globals()["List_up"+str(i)].append(globals()["sig_"+str(i)].iloc[z,0])
            elif globals()["sig_"+str(i)].ix[z,'FoldChange']<=1.5:
                globals()["List_down"+str(i)].append(globals()["sig_"+str(i)].iloc[z,0])
        sets_up.append(set(globals()["List_up"+str(i)]))
        sets_down.append(set(globals()["List_down"+str(i)]))

    common_up=list(set.intersection(*sets_up))
    common_down=list(set.intersection(*sets_down))
    common=common_up + common_down

    for x in range(0, len(common)):
        df.loc[x,md_input.columns[c]]=common[x]

df.to_csv("Output.xls",sep="\t", index=False)
```